# Coherence not respond to another request when it already working on one

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

In project we are using Coherence server. When we are sending request 'A' from a resource. The request 'A' takes several time give response. Meanwhile on the same time when we are sending another request 'B' from another resource it holds 'B' until 'A' is not completed.

I want to make it as it should respond both the requests if at a single time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to address your question on using Oracle Coherence but your question is too generic for me to understand what you are asking.

Could you restate your question with more details ?

What is request A?  Specifically, is it a cache update/get/remove? Is it an invocation?

What is request B? Does request B access the same key if it is also a cache update/get/remove.

It is not possible to understand what operation you want to run in parallel and if it is possible from the above description.